# Why doesn't my SVG:circle show up when I append it to a different class?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Here I have a JSFiddle:

'http://jsfiddle.net/reko91/66m1q9g2/'

I made a function to make circles. Now in this function I have to select an area which to append my circle :

```
var circle = d3.select("#" + area)
    .append("svg:circle");
```

Now I draw two circles :

```
createCircle("svg", 100,100,50,"red"); // here i select the SVG - it works 
createCircle("canvas", 200,200,50,"green"); // here i select the canvas - doesnt work
```

When I append the circle to the `SVG` i created it works, but not when I append it to the `canvas` i made.

What stupid mistake have i made ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An SVG `<rect>` element is not a [container](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/intro.html#TermContainerElement) and cannot be the parent of another `<rect>` or `<circle>` element. Make the second circle a sibling of the first.